# SSRS multi-value parameter with JOIN() function not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have been following [this website](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/09/efficient-way-of-using-all-as-parameter.html) for implementing an optional multi-value parameter. The weird thing is it only works in following conditions:

1. "All" (the one with value -1) is selected. Or
2. Only 1 value is selected.

If I select more than 1 values, it will always come out with no result. I have also tried to print out the value of `=IIF(Parameters!Employee_ID.Value(0)=-1,Nothing,Join(Parameters!Employee_ID.Value,","))`, the output is correct. When `-1` is selected, it's value is nothing, when other results are selected, it will display every value splitted with `','`. Any idea? My parameter value is integer.

**UDPATE**
I found that when I select more than 1 value it will come out no result is because it will always take the 1st value only. For example, if I have selected 4 values which are `4,5,7,9` it will treat it as `WHERE id IN (4)`, instead of `WHERE id IN (4,5,7,9)`. Why?

Comment: Are you using a Stored Procedure or a query directly in your dataset?

Comment: Try Parameters!Employee_ID.Value.Length > 0

Comment: @AlanSchofield dataset

Comment: @Lucky I think this isn't the problem. The problem in on the `Join()` function

Answer (score 1):

If your query is directly in the dataset then you don;t really need to use Join or Split or anything else.

Try the following.

Change you parameter back to the default of text (I know it's a number but that's OK).

Then simply change your query to something like

```
SELECT * 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE (EmployeeID IN(@Employee_ID) OR @Employee_ID = -1)
```

SSRS will take you dataset query and inject the parameters for you as comma separated values automatically. There is no need to do anything with the parameter input.